# Update data from API every second

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

I'm currently working for a school project where I'm working with the Spotify API. Now I've got so far that I receive the current song someone is listening to right now.

But the problem is, that information is only received once the site has been refreshed or opened, but I want it to keep refreshing every second (without refreshing the whole page) so it's up to date with the listener. Does anyone here have any idea on how I can accomplish that?

This is the AJAX request I'm using (I'm not sure if it's useful or anything)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    success: function(response) {
      userInfoPlaceholder.innerHTML = userInfoTemplate(response);
        console.log(response);
      $('#login').hide();
      $('#loggedin').show();
    }
});
```

If there is any other code that I need to post in order to help, please let me know!

Comment: You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run code every x milliseconds.

Comment: wrap your code above in a function, and then set an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to cause the function to be executed repeatedly at the frequency you set. Hint: once per second is probably too often - there's a good chance you won't even have received a response to the previous request before you're firing the next one. There's a good chance the data will arrive out of sequence, or the page's performance will start to degrade, or the server will block you for spamming it with requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spotify Webhooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528806/spotify-webhooks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using setTimeout or setInterval.

The difference is that setInterval executes given function **again and again** at the specified time intervals (until clearInterval() function is called); setTimeout executes given function **one time** just after the specified time interval.

After you complete the necessary process with the response. You can call makerequest() function recursively at the end of the function. The line includes comment provides makerequest() function to be called after 10s again.

```
function makerequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success: function(response) {
            userInfoPlaceholder.innerHTML = userInfoTemplate(response);
            console.log(response);
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#loggedin').show();
            //process with the response and other stuffs
            setTimeout(makerequest, 10000); //recursive call
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: "You can call makerequest() function recursively at the end of the function."... you should actually show an example of that, then we have got a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, your code doesn't wait for the previous call to complete before making the next request. It starts the timeout immediately after launching the ajax request. If you wanted it to wait until ajax had completed before starting the timer again, you'd have to put the call to "setTimeout" inside the "success" callback. Otherwise, using timeout is pretty much pointless, you could just use setInterval instead.

Comment: Thank you for correction ADyson. Also, I corrected and detailed my explanation about the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `setInterval`. which will call a function in every defined seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
   callAjax();
}, 1000);

var callAjax = function(){
  // Write you ajax here
}
```